# Does RIA Services support Entities that are Sub types?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

Here's my entity framework model:
[image]

Here's the domain service class dialog:
[image]

I can't select the Debit or Credit entities in the domain service class dialog. Can I not use these entities in my Silverlight client?

Comment: I found these 2 topics: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/189873/437184.aspx and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/67205ca8-7d77-499c-b076-bb0ba32d63a2 I'll report my progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the entities, and by selecting the base entity, you get access to the child entities.  You just don't get specific queries and metadata except for the base entity